having problem with primeng table height and width issue
i need to have a table with 50 rows scroll, but it must be fitted perfectly in ng-content,
when i try to manipulate table height i fail.
table component
<p-panel header="აქტიური სია" @myInsertRemoveTrigger>
  <div #tableDiv class="">
    <p-table
      [columns]="activeListTableColumns"
      [value]="tableData.data"
      dataKey="id"
      [paginator]="true"
      [rows]="20"
      [scrollable]="true"
      [scrollHeight]="'800px'"
      [lazy]="true"
      (onLazyLoad)="lazyLoad($event)"
      [totalRecords]="tableData.total"
      [tableStyle]="{ 'min-width': '150rem' }">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          @for(column of columns; track $index) {
            <th>{{ column.header }}</th>
          }
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
          @for(column of columns; track $index) {
            <td>{{ rowData[column.field] }}</td>
          }
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
  </div>
</p-panel>

layout component
<main class="flex flex-column gap-1 h-full">
  <p-menubar class="fadein animation-duration-2000 animation-ease-in-out" [model]="menuItems">
    <ng-template pTemplate="start">
      <div class="flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center gap-1">
        <img ngSrc="assets/svg/tbc.svg" height="40" class="mr-2" alt="tbc" width="40"/>
        <span class="font-bold">Risk Check Engine</span>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="end">
        <p-chip styleClass="pl-0 pr-3">
          <span class="bg-primary border-circle w-2rem h-2rem flex align-items-center justify-content-center">{{authService.getUser().fullName[0]}}</span>
          <span class="ml-2 font-medium">{{authService.getUser().fullName}}</span>
        </p-chip>
        <p-button icon="pi pi-sign-out" [rounded]="true" severity="danger" [outlined]="true" (click)="logout()"></p-button>
    </ng-template>
  </p-menubar>

  <div class="fadein animation-duration-2000 animation-ease-in-out h-full">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</main>

i have tried setting [scrollHeight]="'flex'" and also [scrollHeight]="calcHeight()", but nothing seems to work. my only solution to this is to set static height, for example 800px and have some bits of whitespace left over at end of the page, that is bugging me.
does anybody have this issue or any solves for this ?

please share a minimal code, issue reproducible stackblitz for debugging!
